# Non blocking pyplot GUI for GDB python pretty printer

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, gdb, pretty-print

I just want to use matplotlib to visualize some data when debugging. Follow this page: [Analyzing C/C++ matrix in the gdb debugger with Python and Numpy - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/669606/Analyzing-C-Cplusplus-matrix-in-the-gdb-debugger-w), it works OK unless the matplotlib GUI just block the GDB's command line. Which means if I leave the GUI window open, the GDB's command line is freezed, and I can't enter anything in the GDB command until I close the pyplot window.

To solve this, I just try to run the plotting code in another thread, to simplify the test case, I just create a simple python source code named "test-pyplot.py" with the contents below

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from threading import Thread

class MyThread (Thread):

    def __init__(self, thread_id):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.thread_id = thread_id

    def run(self):
        x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1);
        y = np.sin(x)
        plt.plot(x, y)
        plt.show(block = True) #this cause the mainloop

thread1 = MyThread(1)
thread1.start()
```

Now, under the GDB command line, I simply type: `source test-pyplot.py`, and a non blocking GUI will open and it looks good, that GDB's command line can still accept command, so far so good.

But the problem happens when I close the plot window, then I run the `source test-pyplot.py` again, this time, GDB just hangs.

I'm using python 2.7.6 under Windows, and I see that matplotlib was default to use the `tkAgg` as the drawing back end, so I try to see whether this will happen for a normal tk GUI window. Here is another test python file named "test-tk.py", which has contents below:

```
from Tkinter import *
from threading import Thread
class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.g=Tk()
        self.th=Thread(target=self.g.mainloop)
        self.th.start()
    def destroy(self):
        self.g.destroy()
a1 = App()
```

If I run the command `source test-tk.py` under GDB prompt, a tk window will show up, GDB is still alive(not freezed), and I can close the tk window, and type the command `source test-tk.py` again, and every thing works fine, GDB does not hang. I can even run the command `source test-tk.py` twice without close the first tk window, then there will be two tk window shown.

Question: how to correctly show matplotlib pyplot figure in non-blocking mode, which don't hang GDB? Thanks.
Normally, `plt.show` will internally call the `mainloop` function of the Tkinter package, which is a event loop.
matplotlib do have an option named interactive mode, which can be enabled by calling the `plt.ion()', but it don't solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

There's multiple issues.  And FWIW I think I looked into this exact issue once before, search gdb bugzilla.

Anyway, one issue is that you should probably run the GUI in a separate thread.  This avoids the lack of main-loop integration.  This is a bit tougher to program, though you can use Python tricks to make it less painful.

Also, GUI toolkits typically mess with SIGCHLD, which breaks gdb.  So you have to use a hack to deal with this.

You can see how I dealt with these problems in my proof-of-concept gdb GUI: https://gitorious.org/gdb-gui

Comment: Hi, Tom, thanks for the reply. Search the gdb bugzilla, I found one: [gdb hangs after plotting with matplotlib](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14382), there you also mentioned SIGCHLD. I have a glance at your gdb-gui source code, you create a .so to fix those kind of signal issue, understand this hack is a bit hard for me, because it looks like it is for non-Windows system only. BTW, you suggest that run the GUI in a separate thread, yes, I did run my python plot code in a separate thread, and all the main-loop function were running in the separate thread.

Comment: It looks like Ipython did fix this issue, see this post: https://sourceforge.net/p/matplotlib/mailman/message/9333243/ and [Plotting with matplotlib](http://heim.ifi.uio.no/inf3330/scripting/doc/python/ipython/node14.html), also I see Wing IDE also has this fixed, see: http://wingware.com/doc/howtos/matplotlib

Comment: Hi, Tom, you are right, in my code, the GUI is created in the main thread, and the gui event loop is running in a separate thread. But if I change all the code in a separate thread, just like the page you created in [The Cliffs of Inanity › 10. Wacky stuff - tromey.com](http://tromey.com/blog/?p=550), I still have the problem. I see that a lot of shell have "integrated GUI event loop", see:[IPython GUI Support Notes — IPython 3.0.0-dev documentation](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/development/inputhook_app.html)

Comment: [IEP can integrate the event loop](http://www.iep-project.org/iepwizard.html#configuring-shells) and [pydev can have GUI Event Loop Integration](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html#gui-event-loop-integration), can GDB have this implemented?